# Xcode requires development team on each build/run

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode14

Before upgrading Xcode to 14.0 version, I didn't have any problems with re-running application on real device - I selected the development team only once, and then made the build/run continuously

Now, after upgrading to Xcode 14.0,  each time after cleaning the build, I have to set the development team again and again on each subsequent build/run

[image]

Comment: I updated my react-native version from 0.69.5 to 0.70.1 at nearly the same time I upgraded my xcode, so I thought this issue was due to react-native or some dependency upgrade. It could also be due to xcode. It does not seem a major issue but definitely is an annoying inconvenience.

Comment: Totally agree, it doesn't affect business logic, or programming solutions - it's just uncomfortable. Hope they fix it in next release

Comment: No, still running through all Pods requiring Development Team

Comment: @spatak did you find any solution for this issue. Its so annoying.

Comment: @F.Fabian not yet mate,  not yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I found following solution on github: [Github Issue Comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402#issuecomment-1201464693)

Add following code snippet to your post install function in the Podfile. It fixed the issue for me in Production (fastlane) and Debug.

```
post_install do |installer|

  ...

  # https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402#issuecomment-1201464693
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end
```